# Uninstall the Magento extension with its associated database tables and settings

Tags: magento

I have created the Magento extension. I have installed and uninstalled it. During the uninstallation, what I found that the associated database tables are not being deleted and the settings from the `core_config_data` and `core_resource`. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 6):

When removing files of an extension, the data stored in the database (dedicated tables and config in `core_config_data`) are not deleted.

To do this, you have two choice, create a sql upgrade setup to delete those entries, and upgrade your extension, or manually do it in phpmyadmin.

Even if it's not recommanded, I always use the second one, I just run queries likes

```
DROP TABLE 'mytable';
DELETE FROM 'core_config_data' WHERE path LIKE '%mymodule%';
```

Of course the cleanest way would be the other, create these request in a sql file upgrade from your version to the next and run it by upgrading the version in the `etc/config.xml` on the extension.

If the extension is not yours, I suggest to look at `system.xml` and/or other xml files from the `etc/` folder of your module to find informations store in core_config_data, then in all files from the sql/ folder to find other information (table, columns, row added).

Comment: Can you tell me that how can i define the upgrade in the config.xml file? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With some extensions an additional attribute related entry to is added.
So apart from removing entry from core_config_data this also needs to be removed.

```
$eav->addAttribute('customer', 'some_property', array(
    'label'     => 'some label',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
    'position'  => 1,
));
```

Comment: yes +1 for you it was my point, table, column or rows can be added via sql setup, so it could be drop a table, alter a table to remove a column or just delete some rows